# PowerBI date filteration is not applying the filter to leads table inside report

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-365

I am having a powerbi report for leads/opportunities of dynamics 365.

I created a new date table and added a column to it as Calendar('1/1/2021','31/12,2021)

the table is created successfully
then i am marking this table as date table
then i am creating a relationship between the column in the newly created table and the createdon table inside the leads
then i am adding a slicer control on the report to filter the leads by the date

but the filteration is not working fine as soon as i move the slicer, all the leads get hidden.

any ideas why that is not working??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a screenshot could help, but is the slicer based on the date in the calendar date or on the createdon date ? Maybe you should try to switch the column you use in your slicer.

Comment: the slicer is from the date table, because i want the slicer to filter multiple tables not just one

Comment: no, it just clears every visual when applying the filter

Comment: Teh only explanation I see is the link between your date table and your createdon table didn't work as expected, Did you display your date table ? do you have every date you specified in your interval ?

Comment: this is the problem, the data table is becoming empty and no records there showing

Comment: You should display both table separately, maybe the value is not the same type in the columns you are trying to link, did you have any error when trying to link them ?